# C# - SIP Control

Tags: c#, sip

Ok, I have a VOIP Phone. I know the IP address and the port of the phone and have full access to the phone, which I am using to make SIP calls via a SIP trunk.

I basically want to see what is going on on the phone at any given time and I don't know where to start.

If I started, initially, using Wireshark what type of network traffic would I need to look for?

Could I use Putty and view activity on the phone that way?

What part of the .Net framework would provide functionality for interfacing with a VOIP phone?

Thanks

Comment: you can either communicate with the phone via SIP (there are 3rd-party libraries for this) or you need to tell much more about the phone (like what OS etc.) and then perhaps someone can give you an answer...

Comment: You're on! The phone is a Splicecom PCS520. It is hooked up to a Splicecom Maximiser. The Splicecom Maximiser runs a linux based OS in RAM which manages the phones, SIP trunks etc. It has 15 ports, each labeled 5001 to 5015. This is what the VOIP phone plugs into and it is this I want to access to get information. I know the IP address of the maximiser and have the login details for the LDAP database, but my previous attempts to access this database have failed. I can however login to the 'Manager' system via a web browser to control elements of the system.

Comment: Another note. Somebody who previously worked here wrote a CTI application in C#, which returned all of this information. It was very specific down to the individual digits being dialed by a user, as they were being dialed, the number of the person calling them if they were on an inbound call and the number the person was dialing if they were on an outbound call. To be brutally honest, I have the source code and I can compile and run it to get this information, but I can't understand it, I'm just not at that level so I am looking for guidance on where to start.

Comment: CTI app means he probably used TAPI (Splicecom delivers a TAPI provider)... for some options see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Most) VOIP phones uses UDP communication, so you would use the UDP functionality in .NET. This can be raw sockets or the [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class, which is a nice starting point.

You can look in Wireshark for UDP communication that has the phone IP as endpoint. You should try to get the network protocol documentation for your specific protocol/phone, or it is likely to take you a very long time to deduce the messages you need to send.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark has a built-in SIP processor

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.splicecom.com/document-area/doc_download/272-maximiser-protocol-a-port-information-for-ip-networks they have several protocols providing different information which you can access to achieve what you describe.

Another option is to use the the TAPI provider they offer to access the information you want.

Some starting points for TAPI via .NET:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/devangpro.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CShart_TAPI_3x.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734214.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Another option is to build a SIP proxy which allows you to do all sorts of things including the things you described:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SIP_stack_with_SIP_proxy.aspx
- http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/
- http://www.independentsoft.de/sip/index.html
- http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx
- http://www.voiceelements.com/Products/VEToolkit.aspx